# Read a file, and print a specific line of it in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file say 1.txt, and each line contains a string and two numbers. I know the letter such as A in some line, but I don't know the numbers with it. The question is I need to find such line with the specific letter and print out the whole line including the unknown numbers.

Comment: Please provide more details? Some code, some more info on the strings that are in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear to me what you are looking for. But based on your comment on other answers I assume that your problem is as following:

> You have a text file that contains lines. In every line of this text
>   file there could be a sequence of 'A' followed by any 2 numbers. eg: A21,
>   A00, A34 etc. So, you are looking for a way to find such sequences.

Based upon this I have found a solution what I think could do your work. Well the code works like this. It will first of all read every line of the text file and then simply check if there is a letter `A` in the line. If yes, then I'll check if the next 2 letters following A are numbers. If they are numbers then I simply print the A along with the 2 numbers.

Here is my sample code:

```
file = open('c:\\1.txt','r')
searchLetter = "A"
for line in file.readlines():
    if searchLetter in line:
        positionOfA = line.index(searchLetter)
        if line[positionOfA+1].isdigit() & line[positionOfA+2].isdigit():
            print searchLetter+line[positionOfA+1]+line[positionOfA+2]
```

To test this code create a text file named a `1.txt` in your `c:\` directory with the following content:

```
Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
2A21kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
432hhhhhA43hhhh
```

I tested this code and the output was as following:

```
A21
A43
```

**Update:** Using regular expressions simplifies the solution further. Because the code above won't work fine if you have more than one `A` in one line. So here is the better solution.

```
import re
file = open('1.txt','r')
for line in file.readlines():
    sequence = re.findall(r"A\d\d", line)
    if sequence:
        for i in sequence:
            print i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read lines  and can have a check on it...

```
file = open('1.txt','r')
for line in file.readlines():
    if line == 'A12':
       print line, 'this what you are looking for'
```

Comment: You need to strip a newline from `line` before the comparison. Also, drop `.readlines()` (`file` is already an iterator).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what the specific line is, A12 is just an example. The only thing I know is for some line, it contains a string A, and I don't know the numbers with it. But I need to get these numbers and print them along with the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each lines of the file and display lines which contains `A12`:

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == 'A21':
            print(line)
```